# open and close submenus on click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I have a main menu that will display the submenus with a click event in jquery (client wanted to be click instead hover) so I got it working however I still can't figure out one thing: I have the menu and submenus working properly so when I click on "news" the submenu slides down nicely and when I click back on "news" it closes back, however if after openening news' submenu and I click on "resources" the respective submenu appears but news' submenu stays open, I want the previous submenu to close when clicking on another menu item or outside the main menu area any ideas? here's what I got:

```
<ul id="MainMenu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li>
              <a href="#">News</a>
              <ul class="noJS">
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 6</a></li>
            </ul>                         
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Resources</a>
            <ul class="noJS">
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="lastChild"><a href="#">New Button</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and the jquery:

```
    $(function(){
$('#MainMenu').find('> li').click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul')
    .stop(true, true).slideToggle(400); 
    return false;       
});    
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$(function() {
    $('#MainMenu > li').click(function(e) { // limit click to children of mainmenue
        var $el = $('ul',this); // element to toggle
        $('#MainMenu > li > ul').not($el).slideUp(); // slide up other elements
        $el.stop(true, true).slideToggle(400); // toggle element
        return false;
    });
    $('#MainMenu > li > ul > li').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();  // stop events from bubbling from sub menu clicks
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ssu32/

Comment: it works! however I can't get the submenus to close when clicking somewhere else on the page

Comment: Can you make an example so I can troubleshoot off yours?  I can only assume what the issue is.  I'm guessing you would need to bind click to your body/html and make the elements slideup

Answer (score 3):

Just Add this line into your code

```
$('#MainMenu > li').not(this).find('ul').slideUp();
```

**FULL CODE**

```
$('#MainMenu').find('> li').click(function() {
    $('#MainMenu > li').not(this).find('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle(400);
    return false;
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZpeLG/)**