# How can i close my jquery menu

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, menu

I need it to close when i click on a link but how?

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <a href="" class="menuIcon"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="clearfix"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Diensten">Diensten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Over">Het Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Werkwijze">Werkwijze</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```js
var menu = $('nav ul');
$(".menuIcon").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    menu.removeAttr('style');
    menu.slideToggle();
    $(".nav").toggleClass("list");
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364183/open-and-close-submenus-on-click-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Try using the .hide() function inside of the click event of your choice:

```
$('.nav li a').click(function(){
    menu.hide();
});
```